# How to get user defined language in Notepad++ to follow master formatting?

Tags: script, notepad++, language, themes

I have successfully created a user defined language file in Notepad++ and this file has formatting, highlighting, etc.

What I am hoping to do however is tie these into the main theme is. But it looks like each of these are defined separately (see \Notepad++\themes*.xml files).

Is there a good way to incorporate a custom language into these? Or is my only bet to write a script to merge the userDefineLang.xml with the themes?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the style you want from the file `stylers.xml` and modify it into your own style. It is located in `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\stylers.xml`.